# Looking for Dragon Magazine issue promoting 3E Barbarian class

Tags: adnd-2e, dnd-3e, content-identification

The issue was released some months before 3rd Edition made it to the stores; at the beginning of it there was a section describing how the barbarian class worked in 3E, including a sidebar extolling the virtues of playing a 3rd Edition Barbarian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Dragon 272](https://archive.org/details/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine272/page/n23/mode/2up) was part of a series of "Countdown to 3e!" features, which covered the core classes in 3e.

I wasn't able to find the exact phrase "Why play a 3rd Edition barbarian," but there is a side bar with bullet points highlighting the features of the barbarian class, and half of the article is about the barbarian.